# XCode Auto-Indent moves viewModifiers 1 tab too far after a single line with a closing bracket

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, indentation, auto-indent

When I hit re-indent in my XCode project all lines that begin with a . (e.g. ViewModifiers) on a new line after a single line with only a closing bracket are moved 1 tab too far to the right.

I.e. what should indent to

```
Button(
  // Button code
)
.accentColor(.black)
```

indents to

```
Button(
  // Button code
)
  .accentColor(.black)
```

This used to work the upper way until a few XCode-versions or so, and since then it has been the lower style.

Is there a setting or possible XCode-extension that can fix this type of alignment?

Comment: I believe it is a bug. You should write a Feedback.

Comment: @dasdom Thanks, good to know this is not supposed to happen! Just submitted an official bug-report :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually for all time of SwiftUI usage never met such problem (while, yes, now I see it). I assume it is a question of code styling, `cause I never used closing single` )` and moreover use it at all.

The reason of `sugar` style of ending closures which mostly and widely used, like

```
Button("Button") {
  // Action code
}
.accentColor(.black)
```

and with single `}` there is no such problem with auto-indentation.

So my recommendation is just `change coding style to standard and forget about it`.